# Get handle of Object in AutoCAD 2015 from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, handle, autocad

I have managed to link my Visual Studio to my AutoCAD 2015, but I am struggling to get a handle on a text object within my AutoCAD project from vb.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or tips as to how I could get a handle on an AutoCAD object from my vb code.

Ultimately I want to be able to change the text of this object from my vb code.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated..

Thank You in adavance

Comment: you'll need to decide how: (1) ask user to select an object or (2) filter by some criteria

Comment: What Augusto said + you don't need the handle to change the object's properties, you need the object. You generally get it by the `ObjectId`

Comment: Do you know of any sites or links that could help me with using ObjectId? @CADbloke

Comment: Yup, there's a lot of links etc. in the tag wiki @ http://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info. There are a couple of links to forums there which would be useful for you to ask questions after you've had a play. FYI most tags will have a wiki. Click the tag to go to its page of questions, then look for the "more info" link.

Comment: This thread: http://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=32381.0 is a good one for getting started in AutoCAD and .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you start with [My First Plugin](http://www.autodesk.com/myfirstautocadplugin) tutorial then this [AutoCAD .NET Training](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad2016_dot_net_training.zip) material (full list of training material [here](http://www.autodesk.com/developautocad)) that is presented at [this video](http://download.autodesk.com/media/adn/DevTV_Introduction_to_AutoCAD._NET_Programming/).

Here is a quick example on how list all AutoCAD entities on Model Space:

```
[CommandMethod("listAllOnModelSpace")]
public static void CmdListAllEntitiesOnModelSpace()
{
  Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
  using (Transaction trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
    BlockTableRecord mSpace = trans.GetObject(SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db), OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
    foreach(ObjectId entityId in mSpace)
    {
      Entity entity = trans.GetObject(entityId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity;
    }
    trans.Commit();
  }
}
```

Just had this in C#, but you may translate to VB.NET [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).