# Get ObjectId from AutoCAD

Tags: vb.net, autocad, objectid

I am currently using VB to add functionality into AutoCAD.

I am trying to get a handle on the ObjectId of my Text Object, I was wondering if there was a way for me to view the ObjectId straight from Autocad (maybe in some type of properties viewer?)

Any help or advice on how i could do this would be helpful, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ObjectId of any AutoCAD entity is for programming use only, there is no UI feature to see it (unless you develop a plugin).

Also, the actual ID number will change from one session to another. It's just a number used to open and manipulate entities in memory faster. The ObjectId is not save into the .dwg file. If you close and open a drawing, all IDs will be different.

Now the Handle is persistent (saved into .dwg files) and don't change between sessions.

**NOTE:** there are some scenario where the Handle also changes, like for entities inside a block during a BEDIT command.

Here is a quick sample to loop through entities using VBA/ActiveX

```
Public Sub LoopMText()
    For i = 0 To ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count - 1
        If TypeOf ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(i) Is AcadMText Then
            Dim t As AcadMText
            Set t = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(i)
            If t.TextString = "something here" Then
                ' do something...
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I see, The reason I ask, is because I want to get a handle on a specific text object within my AutoCAD from my VB (For Editing), I thought the objectId would be the way to do this but apparently not, Do you know of a way I could do this?

Comment: you can select by clicking on it (ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity) or do a loop on all entities to select what you need (ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item collection)

Comment: I see, Do you think you could help me with some syntax for Looping through the Entire drawing (paper space layouts) that will catch any Objects with a certain Text value?

Comment: see edited answer above, did not fully tested it... sorry, in a hurry.

Comment: VBA is fine, I should be able to work with this. Much appreciated!

Comment: check this, should give a C# (.NET) sample that you can translate to VB.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125471/get-handle-of-object-in-autocad-2015-from-vb-net/33218451#33218451